# Problem with linking C library to Qt project

Tags: c++, c, qt

I know this is a 100times discussed topic, but after number of attempts, I just can't find the solution since don't understand the situation - no errors.
I am trying to connect dll "C" library to my project and receiving some crazy code in App output "...exited with code -1073741515" as well as empty console with Press  to close this window...

So, here are mine:
mylib.c:

```
#include "mylib.h"
int mysum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

mylib.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT int mysum(int, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

testlib.pro:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../TestDLL/ -lmylib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../TestDLL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../TestDLL

HEADERS += \
    ../../../../TestDLL/mylib.h
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "mylib.h"
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug()<<mysum(1,2);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I think, I am missing something with linkage in pro file, but can't get what.
TestDLL is the folder with:

> mylib.dll mylib.h mylib.c libmylib.a

to build the dll I've used:

```
gcc -c mylib.c
gcc -shared -o mylib.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libmylib.a mylib.o
```

Will be appreciated for some hints... Thank you

Comment: `-1073741515` is `0xC0000135`, which, in turn, is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 2):

You have to manipulate the compiler options such that:

1. When building the library, you have

   ```
   #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
   ```
2. When using the library, you have

   ```
   #define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
   ```

One way to do this is to use:

```
#if defined(BUILD_DLL)
   #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And then use `-DBUILD_DLL` when building the DLL and leave it undefined when using the DLL.

Comment: @R Sahu, thank you! Can you please also add line about moving dll file to debug folder, thus I will mark your message as an answer?

Comment: @AlexanderLyapin, what is the "moving dll file to debug folder" problem?

Comment: During therunning the TestDll program, the mylib.dll file was outside the debug/release folder, thus getting those code. I've added it in debug/release folder (also tryed option with linkin it using pro file) and everything works.

Comment: @AlexanderLyapin, I completely missed that. Thanks for clarifying. Looks like you were stuck on one problem while I was giving you a solution to a second problem.

Comment: @R Sahu, but your hints are also really usefull!

Answer (score 1):

So, what I've changed following @R Sahu hints:

in mylib.h :

```
#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and for compiling dll:

```
gcc -c -DBUILDING_DLL mylib.c
gcc -shared -o mylib.dll mylib.o -Wl,--out-implib,libmylib.a
```

Plus in .pro file:

```
LIBS += "$$PWD/../../../../TestDLL/mylib.dll"
```

I believe, the line in .pro file is the most important. Now everything works fine.